# jQuery specific event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a unordered list with an event handler attached using jQuery

```
<ul class='menu'>
  <li id='1'>Home</li>
  <li id='2'>item 1</li>
  <li id='3'>item 2</li>
</ul>

$('.menu').on('click','li',function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  // do navigation stuff
});
```

What I want to do is have an event trigger that when I return to this list it automatically selects the option that I selected previously.  I have everything else working except this trigger.  Any help would be great in guiding me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "return to this list"?

Comment: Sorry for being too vague, this is for a menu that has sub menus.  What happens is when the user clicks a menu item and then selects a sub menu item it takes them away from the page.  I log the option they select but when they come back to the menu, I want them to have that menu option selected and then they just have to choose the submenu item they want to go to next.  Hope that made sense.

Comment: If you are leaving the page and then returning, you'll need to persist that value somewhere, like a cookie or localStorage, then read the value back in when the page loads.

Comment: Then the easiest way is to keep record of the element id on the server of in the browser e.g. cookie / localstorage. I would use numerical id's like item1-10 where 1 is main menu id and 10 the submenu id. Then you can select it with $("#item1-10") in jQuery

Comment: Is this custom menu or using any CMS like Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your selection in a variable and use that to trigger the click on the correct `<li>`:

```
var lastSelected = 1;

$('.menu').on('click','li',function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  // do navigation stuff

  lastSelected = $(this).attr('id'); //save the id
});
```

To trigger the event later, use:

```
$('#'+lastSelected).trigger('click');
```